# How to remove session attribute on jspDestroy() method

Tags: jsp, session, httprequest, page-lifecycle

I want to remove session attribute when jsp page is destroyed. My problem is that I can not call request.getSession() on jspDestroy() method. Compilation error:

```
public void jspDestroy() {
  request.getSession().removeAttribute("key");
}
```

> Error: request can not be resolved!

Is there any way to remove session attribute after jsp page destroy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The jspDestroy() method is only called when the JSP container is shut down** , not after processing each request.

So it doesn't have access to any of the implicit JSP objects (request, response) (since they are local variables in the _jspService() method).

So, you cannot access the `request` and the `response` implicit Objects in jspDestroy() (because basically there is no logical explanation why to do that). The destruction phase of the JSP [life cycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_life_cycle.htm) is when a JSP is being **removed from use by a container** (web server).

In your case, what i suspect is that your logic is incorrect. I think you should reconsider when the session attribute is removed...

Answer (score 0):

NO you cannot because it is not valid. A session is relative to a request (and a user) and session interaction happens when a user is in conversation with the server (as part of a http request).

The destroy (and the init) methods on the other hand are not bound to the request life cycle and are server events bound to the Servlet life cycle.

Perhaps if you tell us what you are trying to achieve, an alternative can be suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. Can we define request at global variable and assign value while init() method. After that, can I use this request global variable from destroy() method? Is this be alternative way?

Comment: No. A request object is transient and created per browser request. Every browser click or a form post creates a request object on the server. The request object is cleaned up after the response is written to the browser. Think of it this way - your jsp serves all logged in users who have a session with your application. The jspDestroy() gets called only once, Whose session will you invalidate? To reiterate jspDestroy is a server side event and has no relation to the request object.